# Partition Key on dynamo db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having use case where I want to add record into dynamo db. I have some set of attribute along with hash value which always unique in each request. Would it be good idea to use this hash value column as partition key or GSI ?
If I make it as partition key then would it always keep new record in the new partition because my hashvalue always be unique ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a GSI only if you need to do queries based on columns other than the primary hash.

DynamoDB allocates additional partitions to a table in the following situations:

- If you increase the table's provisioned throughput settings beyond
  what the existing partitions can support.
- If an existing partition
  fills to capacity and more storage space is required.

Read more on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html)

Comment: sorry for bad description. i am having 10 columns where 1 of column having hash value which is unqiue. i want to know can I create partition key on hash value column?

Comment: Updated answer based on the change

Comment: my primary partition key is some other id and want to retrieve records using column which contains unique random value. can i use this unique random value column as GSI?